# If then statement with date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I asked a question this morning regarding changing the date format in VBA, and I've found a partial solution from other discussions:

So I have the following dates (in ddmmyyyy format) in Excel

```
   A
1/7/2018
2/7/2018
19/5/2018
2/12/2018
31/12/2018
17/6/2018
12/3/2018
17/6/2018
12/3/2018
```

I use the following code in VBA to change them to date:

```
Sub convert()

Dim i As Long


finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 1 To finalrow

Cells(i, 2).Value = CDate(Cells(i, 1))
Next i

End Sub
```

and obtained the following:

```
  A           B
1/7/2018    1/7/2018
2/7/2018    2/7/2018
5/19/2018   19/5/2018
2/12/2018   2/12/2018
12/31/2018  31/12/2018
6/17/2018   17/6/2018
12/3/2018   12/3/2018
6/17/2018   17/6/2018
12/3/2018   12/3/2018
```

So my problem now is the original ddmmyyyy now becomes a messy combination of mmddyyyy and ddmmyyyy.

I know the cdate have effectively changed the entire date format to mmddyyyy, but it confuses the date and month for some of the entries.

NOTE: I also tried the popular jeeped's solution but it gives the same messy result.

So now I'm thinking of a solution to use the if-then statement.

If the DAY in the B column (contain mmddyyyy date) exceeds 12, then change the format to ddmmyyyy.

I guess it's something like

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
.TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(2), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
End With

if (**the dd in mmddyyyy exceeds 12**) then 
numberformat = "ddmmyyyy"

end sub
```

So how do I set about doing that?

Comment: Do you know if the date in A1 (1/7/2018) was originally 01-Jul-2018 or 07-Jan-2018 before it was imported? You haven't mentioned where these dates came from. If they were imported properly (by specifying DMY or MDY whichever the original was) then it doesn't matter what date system your computer is on nor what date format you have the cells set to.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped! Just a side note, your solution to the original popular convert text to date is brilliant! It doesn't solve my problem though. The date is just strings of text imported from data entry, a single piece of a much larger problem. It's ddmmyyyy. And I'm looking to change them all to mmddyyyy

Comment: OK, so the whole column is left-aligned, that's the default for text. If any got accidentally converted then some would be right aligned. But these are all left-aligned, correct? And when you narrow the column so the whole string doesn't fit, they either look truncated or spill over into the next column, right? None look like #######.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, it's a combination of both. Some, converted after the code, are right-aligned, while some are left-aligned... The converted ones become ###### while the unconverted ones spills to the other cells

Comment: the converted ones are 7/1/2018
7/2/2018
19/5/2018
12/2/2018
31/12/2018
17/6/2018
3/12/2018
17/6/2018
3/12/2018

Comment: How was the data 'imported'?

Comment: it came from my boss, compiled by the salesperson who uses the ddmmyyyy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid number-only date formats

I have often fallen into the trap of thinking I understand that dates are dd/mm or mm/dd, but I have in fact misunderstood and it is doing something odd like using different conventions on different rows.

I now never use number-only date formats, if I can avoid it. Not only in Excel but elsewhere. Unless it is ordered as yyyy mm dd, which is unlikely to be misentered, misdisplayed or misunderstood.

#### Column A begins as text entered in the spreadsheet, not as a number or date

So where you have written 1-7-2018 and are happily assuming this to be 1 July, it is just text. Excel interprets in its default way (for someone in North America) as 7 Jan. Only when the mm-dd interpretation doesn't work, does Excel try to interpret it as dd-mm. Unfortunately, Excel does this silently.

To avoid this trap, use your second approach, but apply it to the *original* text formatted dates and explicitly tell Excel to interpret them (all) as dd/mm/yyyy.

First tell Excel to *read* the input text as though it is in dd/mm/yyyy format. Do this with the xlDMYFormat option. Note xl *DMY* Format, not *YMD*.

More details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749(v=office.11).aspx

Then tell Excel how to format the *display* of the resulting date, i.e. mm-dd-yyyy, using the ".NumberFormat" option.

#### An example to try

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
.TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
```

This short and easy to follow. Note that:

**FieldInfo** tells Excel how to *interpret* the text string into a date in internal format.

**NumberFormat** tells Excel how to *display* the date, i.e. convert internal format date into a text string.

Comment: Hi @Eureka, that is the popular solution proposed by Jeeped, With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
'    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
'    .NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display


Which i have mentioned also gave the same result

Comment: Try the snippet above. Would be neat.

Answer (score 1):

There is no foolproof method of detecting which format the dates are in.  The macro below depends on there being at least one date in text format.  That will happen if and only if the format of the dates being input differ from the window regional short date setting of the computer, and the "Month" portion is > 12, and also if there are some dates which have been converted (albeit incorrectly) to real dates, and other dates which are text strings.

If your original data source is really **all text** in DMY format, then all you need to do is select the `Text-to-Columns` wizard, and, at the appropriate step, select `DMY` for the column format.

If the original data is **mixed text and "real dates"**, you might find the below macro helpful.  It was written to try to handle that issue, which is what you are running into.

The foolproof solution is to ensure that your DMY sales person inputs dates correctly. Exactly how to do that depends on how he is inputting dates now.

For this macro, the results will be in the numberformat determined by the Windows Regional Short Date settings.  But you can change it as required.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertDates()
    'converts dates that have been mismatched MDY / DMY
    'Assumes dates are all in selected column
    '   Only need to select a single cell in the column
    '   will place results in a column next to original data
    ' If adjacent column is not blank, a column will be inserted
    'Figures out the original format by analyzing a "text" date
    'Time components are converted directly.  This might be OK unless
    ' in a non standard format such as 1400Z

Dim R As Range, C As Range
Dim sDelim As String
Dim FileDateFormat As String * 3
Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant
Dim vDateParts As Variant
Dim YR As Long, MN As Long, DY As Long
Dim TM As Double
Dim vRes As Variant 'to hold the results of conversion

Set R = Selection

'Test that selected cell contains a date
If Not IsDate(R(1)) Then
    MsgBox "Select a cell containing a date"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set R = Intersect(R.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
ReDim vRes(1 To R.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

'Find a "text date" cell to analyze
For Each C In R
    With C
    If IsDate(.Value) And Not IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
        'find delimiter
        For I = 1 To Len(.Text)
            If Not Mid(.Text, I, 1) Like "#" Then
                sDelim = Mid(.Text, I, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next I

        'split off any times
        V = Split(.Text & " 00:00")
        vDateParts = Split(V(0), sDelim)

        If vDateParts(0) > 12 Then
            FileDateFormat = "DMY"
            Exit For
        ElseIf vDateParts(1) > 12 Then
            FileDateFormat = "MDY"
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox "cannot analyze data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    End With
Next C

If sDelim = "" Then
   MsgBox "cannot find problem"
   Exit Sub
End If

'Check that analyzed date format different from Windows Regional Settings
Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder)
    Case 0 'MDY
        If FileDateFormat = "MDY" Then
            MsgBox "File Date Format and Windows Regional Settings match" & vbLf _
                & "Look for problem elsewhere"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Case 1 'DMY
        If FileDateFormat = "DMY" Then
            MsgBox "File Date Format and Windows Regional Settings match" & vbLf _
                & "Look for problem elsewhere"
            Exit Sub
        End If
End Select

'Process dates
'Could shorten this segment but probably more understandable this way
J = 0
Select Case FileDateFormat
    Case "DMY"
        For Each C In R
        With C
            If IsDate(.Value) And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
            'Reverse the day and the month
                YR = Year(.Value2)
                MN = Day(.Value2)
                DY = Month(.Value2)
                TM = .Value2 - Int(.Value2)
            ElseIf IsDate(.Value) And Not IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
                V = Split(.Text & " 00:00") 'remove the time
                vDateParts = Split(V(0), sDelim)
                YR = vDateParts(2)
                MN = vDateParts(1)
                DY = vDateParts(0)
                TM = TimeValue(V(1))
            Else
                YR = 0
            End If

            J = J + 1
            If YR = 0 Then
                vRes(J, 1) = C.Value
            Else
                vRes(J, 1) = DateSerial(YR, MN, DY) + TM
            End If
        End With
        Next C
    Case "MDY"
        For Each C In R
        With C
            If IsDate(.Value) And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
            'Reverse the day and the month
                YR = Year(.Value2)
                MN = Day(.Value2)
                DY = Month(.Value2)
                TM = .Value2 - Int(.Value2)
            ElseIf IsDate(.Value) And Not IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
                V = Split(.Text & " 00:00") 'remove the time
                vDateParts = Split(V(0), sDelim)
                YR = vDateParts(2)
                MN = vDateParts(0)
                DY = vDateParts(1)
                TM = TimeValue(V(1))
            Else
                YR = 0
            End If

            J = J + 1
            If YR = 0 Then
                vRes(J, 1) = C.Value
            Else
                vRes(J, 1) = DateSerial(YR, MN, DY) + TM
            End If
        End With
        Next C
End Select

With R.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn
    Set C = .Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then .EntireColumn.Insert
End With

R.Offset(0, 1).Value = vRes

End Sub
```

**Results in MDY format**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I must say this is a VERY long code for a simple question, but it worked like a charm! This is the one code that really solve the problem, and it should go viral.

Comment: @MT32 Your problem is a subset of what the code was designed for. So once you understand what it is doing, you could shorten it to eliminate the non-applicable portions.  But it probably doesn't cause any harm to have that in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date to ddmmyyyy using format function.

See below code

```
Sub convert()

Dim i As Long


finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 1 To finalrow

Cells(i, 2).Value = Format(CDate(Cells(i, 1)), "d/m/yyyy")
Next i

End Sub
```

Alternatively, try this

```
Sub convert()

Dim i As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim y As Long


finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 1 To finalrow

d = Day(CDate(Cells(i, 1)))
m = Month(CDate(Cells(i, 1)))
y = Year(CDate(Cells(i, 1)))

Cells(i, 2) = d & "/" & m & "/" & y

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, tried it with the dataset, it gives the same messy output.

Comment: Hi, nope it's not working, it's still giving the same result

Comment: @MT32 What is the current date time setting of your system?

Comment: My current system is mmddyyyy. The original dataset is taken from a guy who uses input the data in ddmmyyyy

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
sub convert()

Dim i as Long
Dim d as Integer
Dim m as Integer
Dim y as Integer
Dim holder as String
Dim output as Date

finalrow = cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to finalrow

     holder = cells(i,1).value
     d = Left(holder,2)
     m = Mid(holder,4,2)
     y = Right(holder,4)

     output = DateSerial(y,m,d)

     cells(i,2).value=output
     cells(i,2).NumberFormat="mm/dd/yyyy"

Next i

End Sub
```